# Автоматическая генерация кода на python, т.е. создание программы из программы

Tags: python, xml, поиск-библиотек

Т.е. допустим есть некая среда по типу визуального программирование, в котором путем соединений или выбора паттерна поведения (функции) формируется исходный код. 
Вопрос: как и на чем генерируется код? Есть ли какой-то алгоритм, или библиотека на python позволяющая это делать?
Идеи: создание промежуточного исходного кода в формате XML, и после этого парсить в формат python (.py). 
Заранее извиняюсь, если кому-то покажется вопрос глупым.

Comment: В общем-то ничего не мешает просто "руками" генерировать код, стандартными средствами Python.

Comment: Может подскажите пример реализации?

Comment: Все зависит от того, что выдает визуальный редактор. Для примера можете посмотреть проект [coro-scratch](https://github.com/BookOwl/coro-scratch) - это конвертер из визуального языка Scratch в Python. В любом случае, текст программы - это просто текст, в простейшем случае просто открываете файл и пишете в него команды.

Comment: По поводу текста согласен, просто может кто-то сталкивался с таким и имеются более изящные решения

Comment: В любом случае спасибо за помощь)